# ActionMailer - limit on number of recipients?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, actionmailer

I've got Capistrano set up to send emails after deploying my RoR (2.3.8) application.  I have a `config/cap_mailer.rb` file that basically looks like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => my,
  :port => exchange,
  :domain => server,
  :authentication => settings,
  :user_name => are,
  :password => here
}

class CapMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def deploy_notification(cap_vars)
    recipients  cap_vars[:notify_emails]
    from        'deploy@my.org'
    subject     "New app!"
    body        "Deployed application...blah blah blah"
  end
end
```

Then, in my `deploy.rb` file, I have the following:

```
require 'config/cap_mailer.rb'
...
desc "Email recipients of deployment"
task :notify do
  puts "  * Sending notification email"
  set :notify_emails, ["test1@my.org", "test2@my.org", etc.]
  CapMailer.deliver_deploy_notification(self)
end
```

Now this all works fine and dandy......until I put more than 7 email addresses in the **:notify_emails** array.  Up to 7 works fine, but when I put 8 or more (all valid addresses), the email gets screwed up a little bit (still goes through to the first 7, at least).  Looking at the email header, it shows that it is cutting off the 8th (and 9th, 10th, ...) address from the 'To:' and putting it in the message body.

> HEADER:
>   thread-index: AcyaZxlga08L9p35QYKJ22aiGG2zeA==
>   Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
>   Importance: normal
>   Priority: normal
>   X-MimeOLE: Produced By ...
>   Received: from exchange.my.org ([ip address]) by ...; Thu, 3 Nov 2011 14:28:08 -0600
>   Date: Thu, 3 Nov 2011 14:28:08 -0600
>   From: deploy@my.org
>   To: test1@my.org,
>       test2@my.org,
>       test3@my.org,
>       test4@my.org,
>       test5@my.org,
>       test6@my.org,
>       test7@my.org
>   HEADER:
>   
>   BODY:
>   test8@my.org
>   Message-Id: 
>   <4eb2f95816341_135ff800c21ac130@my_box.local.tmail>
>   Subject: New app!
>   Mime-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Return-Path: deploy@my.org
>   X-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Nov 2011 20:28:08.0494 (UTC) 
>   FILETIME=[19601CE0:01CC9A67]
>   
>   Deployed application...blah blah blah
>   BODY:

In addition, the subject does not appear on the email, even though the "error text" in the message body shows the correct subject.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  What is it about having 8 or more recipients that breaks it?  I've Googled around and can't find anything about ActionMailer having a limit on the number of recipients (even if there were, that's a small limit).  Is there something I'm missing?  Any help is appreciated!  I really need to be able to send to 8 or more recipients.

**UPDATE:**  Setting the **recipients** directly with an array of 8 or more addresses still breaks things, so this clearly seems like a problem with ActionMailer and not Capistrano.

```
recipients ["test1@my.org", "test2@my.org", "test3@my.org", "test4@my.org", 
  "test5@my.org", "test6@my.org", "test7@my.org", "test8@my.org", "test9@my.org"]
```

Comment: I have had similar problems from time to time with our exchange mailserver. Exchange rewrites the headers and foobars the message in the process. You should try with another mailserver and see what happens.

Comment: @Unixmonkey - unfortunately I can't change mail servers (at least for production).  Do you think it may be related to this [Prawn/IE](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/06/02/little-caveat-when-using-ssl-https-and-prawn-which-is-a-pdf-generation-tool-for-rails-on-internet-explorer/comment-page-1/#comment-1277) issue?  The solution presented there worked for my Rails app, so I wonder if explicitly specifying the mail header(s) will similarly solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The 7th email address is not followed by a comma, which could be the problem. Try passing a string to `recipients`, like `cap_vars[:notify_emails].join(',')`, with no newlines.

Comment: But I'm not creating the comma-separated list or doing anything with newlines.  I just pass the :notify_emails array to **recipients** and ActionMailer is doing the rest.  I don't how it's failing to create the correct **To:** string.  I will give it a shot though, and see what happens.

Comment: You might figure it out by watching the smtp conversation with your mail server. Pass `:debug => true` in the ActionMailer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a string to recipients without commas (there have been reports of commas as a problem), like:

```
cap_vars[:notify_emails].join(' ')
```

Comment: Here's one example: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/151792 However...I'm more thinking it's your actual server. I do recommend trying that at least. Are you using a particular server / hosting solution for this application? What is it?

Comment: Yeah, that says passing a comma-delimited string doesn't work, but doesn't imply spaces will work.  The Rails docs say either a singular string address, or an array of string addresses.  I'll try it, but I'm doubting it will work.

As in the two comments to the original post, I think it's something with Exchange (company server).  I think somehow tweaking the headers might work as it does for the Prawn printing in IE.  But I don't know where to start for this problem.

Comment: Who manages your exchange server? have them check recipient maximums for global, user and internet user settings in exchange : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996677(EXCHG.80).aspx I think you're right, has nothing to do with actionmailer or capistrano.

Answer (score -1):

With all respect some simple things that you might overlook in debugging difficult errors:

1. If its mail server related install it on another production server? If you not sure it is the mail server acting up looking for another error may be of no help.
2. Try upgrade rails / ruby ? Perhaps its a bug in the code